# Why am I getting these warnings when I try to installing Pycharm in my Pop!_OS?

Tags: software-installation, python

I am following the instructions in the `readme.txt` file. But for some reason, the software is not being installed.

The instructions of the `readme` file are:

1. Unpack the tar file to the place of installation
2. `cd bin` and run `./pycharm.sh` to start the installation

It is running Pycharm when I am executing .`/pycharm.sh`, but doesn't install it. I want to install it. Thank you for your help.

Here are the warnings when I am trying to install Pycharm

```
$ cd pycharm-community-2020.1.2
$ ls
bin        help   Install-Linux-tar.txt lib        plugins
build.txt  index  jbr                   license    product-info.json 

$ cd bin 
$ ls
format.sh         inspect.sh  pycharm64.vmoptions pycharm.vmoptions
fsnotifier        libdbm64.so pycharm.png          restart.py
fsnotifier64      log.xml     pycharm.sh
idea.properties   printenv.py pycharm.svg

$ ./pycharm.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Gtk-Message: 19:19:34.835: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
2020-07-01 19:19:35,206 [    551]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Resource bundle redefinition for plugin 'com.jetbrains.pycharm.community.customization'. Old value: messages.ActionsBundle, new value: messages.PyBundle
2020-07-01 19:19:36,546 [   1891]   WARN - nsystem.impl.ActionmanagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: com.intellij]
2020-07-01 19:19:36,555 [   1900]   WARN - nsystem.impl.ActionmanagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: com.intellij]
2020-07-01 19:19:36,556 [   1901]   WARN - nsystem.impl.ActionmanagerImpl - keymap "NetBeans 1.0" not found [Plugin: com.intellij]
2020-07-01 19:19:36,556 [   1901]   WARN - nsystem.impl.ActionmanagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: com.intellij]
2020-07-01 19:19:36,662 [   2007]   WARN - nsystem.impl.ActionmanagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: PythonCore]
2020-07-01 19:19:36,662 [   2007]   WARN - nsystem.impl.ActionmanagerImpl - keymap "NetBeans 6.5" not found [Plugin: PythonCore]
2020-07-01 19:19:41,332 [   6677]   WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be 13x13. Please fix ToolWindow (ID: Problems View) or icon jar:file:/home/singh/pycharm-community-2020.1.2/lib/icons.jar!/general/warning.svg
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text, just copy/paste the text in a code block.

Comment: @AndyDalton, the code won't be readable.

Comment: A recent revision suggests otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm Community Edition is a free and open source IDE which is perfect for pure Python coding. To install PyCharm Community Edition in Pop!_OS open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install snapd  
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

The pycharm-community snap package will be updated automatically in the background when updates become available.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: I have both snap store and flatpaks already good to go, but the problem I am facing, with snap app is that I am not able to set the interpreter for these apps. They are using Python 3.7 and I want to use Python 3.8, I will be using this for programming and coding so I will be using Python3.8 to install the modules of Python. For some reason, the interpreter is fixed as python3.7 even when I am trying to change it.
I installed the Pandas modules using python 3.8 and all the modules I installed could be run and imported in ./pycharm.sh.

Comment: It's not a problem because it's easy to change. Look at my screenshot. In the upper right corner is a little green triangle. Next to the green triangle is the showImage (my project) settings. Click the down arrow on showImage (or whatever your project name is), select *Edit Configurations*, and it brings up the project *Run/Debug Configurations* window where you can change the Python interpreter used by your project. I also published a step-by-step [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1173453/).

Comment: To import all installed Python modules put a checkmark beside *Inherit global-site packages* by following this step-by-step [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59367874/) that I wrote. First you need to save your Python code, delete your existing project, and start the same project again as a new project in order for all your installed Python modules to be automatically accessible to your new Python project. In the screenshot in my answer you can see that PyCharm imported Image from PIL with just this single line of code: `from PIL import Image`  .

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Thank you. I am trying out everything you have told me. I have just switched to Linux and I am a noob.

Comment: If you just want to copy/paste and run simple Python code blocks from the terminal you should be using IPython (`sudo apt install python3-ipython`) and only use PyCharm as an IDE for Python code that requires a project.

Comment: Hey man, I fixed the main problem. It worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much Karel. You're the boss. Thank you so so much